# Mysql select distinct user with each of their own preference

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Let's say I have a user and preference table, as well as a bridge table `user_preference` between the two:

```
/* user table:  */
+----------+--------------+
| Field    | Type         |
+----------+--------------+
| id       | int          |
| username | varchar(255) |
+----------+--------------+

/*  preference table: */
+------------+--------------+
| Field      | Type         |
+------------+--------------+
| preference | varchar(255) |
+------------+--------------+

/* user_preference table:  */
+-----------------+--------------+
| Field           | Type         |
+-----------------+--------------+
| user_id         | int          |
| preference_name | varchar(255) |
+-----------------+--------------+
```

For instance there are 3 preferences to choose from: "swimming", "watching TV", "cycling". And one user can have zero or all 3 of the preferences, which is reflected on the `user_preference` table.

Now I want to query 10 different users, and with all of them each of their own preferences included, either null or mutiple preferences, how to construct a select statement for that?

So far I have tried something like this:

```
SELECT u.*, p.preference_name 
FROM user u 
LEFT JOIN user_preference p ON p.user_id = u.id
LIMIT 10;

/* Result:  */
id | username | preference_name

1  | user1    | swimming
1  | user1    | cycling
2  | user2    | null
3  | user3    | watching TV
... /* rest of the result  */
```

As you can see the result will return a duplicate `user1`, and it won't be 10 distinct users. I'm aware of the `distinct` and `group by` keywords, it doesn't solve the problem, as it will only return a single preference for a user, while the user can have multiple preferences.

How to do that with one single select statement?

Comment: By the way, if table `preference` has only a single column, then you don’t need that table at all. The preference column on `user_preference` table suffices. In a sophisticated database such as Postgres (I don’t know about MySQL), you could instead define an [enum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-enum.html), a limited set of known values to be used as the data type of the preference column on `user_preference` table.

Comment: This is standard behavior, it will return a row per unique result. You can make use of functions like `GROUP_CONCAT` (or `SUM` with numbers, for example) with `GROUP BY` to aggregate results. Though it can also be easier to just iterate the result set and keep note of "duplicate" results as "appending" another value for the preference

Comment: @Basil Bourque By the looks of it, mysql does indeed has a enum type, maybe my design should improve based on that, thank you for the advice!

Comment: @Rogue Can you write an answer for that, I'm not sure what part `sum` plays in it, and this is the first time I heard of `GROUP_CONCAT`

Comment: `SUM` was merely an example (if your data type was numbers). `GROUP_CONCAT` will concatenate grouped text fields together with a separator. Try `SELECT u.id, GROUP_CONCAT(p.preference_name) FROM ... GROUP BY u.id` (replacing `...` with the rest of your query)

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] PS When this is clear about exactly what you want it will be a faq. Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. If asking reflect research.

Comment: @philipxy Not sure why I got this, mybe the title? But my situation is not describlable by my current knowledge with sql, and describing an simple example is the best I can do(simple and pretty reproducable BTW), last time I answered a [quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72439574/16648127) got even worse title, and nothing comes to it's attention, maybe it's because the op is a big contributor? I'd like to hear from you what you think

Comment: There is no clear statement of what you want in this post by which one could reasonably search or write a query. "not describlable" is just not so, no need for any SQL knowledge per se is needed to talk about how a result table is a function of input tables, just words that describe tables. PS I don't understand what you mean by "got this". I don't understand what you are trying to say about the link.

Comment: "There is no clear statement of what you want in this post by which one could reasonably search or write a query." Read the post. Try to find it. I'm done.

Comment: Here: Now I want to query 10 different users, and with all of them each of their own preferences

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```sql
SELECT u.*, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT p.preference_name) AS prefs
  FROM user u 
  LEFT JOIN user_preference p ON p.user_id = u.id
 GROUP BY u.id
LIMIT 10;
```

The GROUP_CONCAT() will make a comma-separated list of preferences for each user.

**Pro tip**. When tables get very large, altering ENUMs to add more values gets very time-consuming. Plus, it's usually unwise to design a database so it needs lots of ALTER TABLE statements as it grows. So, the approach you have outlined is the right way to go if you want your possible preferences to be open-ended.